# Change Column headings in results to show only column name, not the table name.column name

Tags: jetbrains-ide, datagrip

can you please tell me how to change the column headers properties so that they only show the column name and not the tableName.ColumnName.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you run a query with several tables join or you just open a table to view data?

Comment: several table joins. The only solution so far has been to use leads.address AS leads. I was hoping in DataGrip there was a setting to just show column names, not table.column name

Comment: Another workaround can be using short aliases for tables

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are using "select * " rather than selecting the individual column names.  Try using "select col1, col2, col3, etc from table". Alternatively you can alias the table name, then do a select *.  e.g. "select * from table A".  Both should give you the column name minus the table prefix.